# BATTERY_PROPERTY returns 0

Tags: android, battery, batterymanager

I'm making a app based on **BatteryManager**. But every `BATTERY_PROPERTY` returns 0. Here's my code:

```
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21){
     BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);

        int remainingCapacityRatio = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
               //print it
        int batteryCapacityMicroAh = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER);
                //print it
        int dischargingTimeSeconds  = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_AVERAGE);
                //print it
        int  currentNow  = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CURRENT_NOW);
                //print it
        long energyCounter  = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_ENERGY_COUNTER);
                //print it
            }
```

Even I use `getLongProperty()`, I only get a fixed value.

I do have the `BATTERY_STATS` permission 
(and `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`, even though it doesn't need it).

And one more thing: Can anybody tell me how can i get the current battery capacity (current, not total)? Can my code above do it?

**Edit 1:** The first one (`remainingCapacityRatio`) works, but i need the other 4 more!

**Edit 2:** There was a guy who ask the same question ([Android BatteryManager returning 0 for all property-retrieval calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280582/android-batterymanager-returning-0-for-all-property-retrieval-calls)), but he didn't get the answer he wanted!

Comment: Running your exact code gave me values for 1,3,4 with the other two at zero.

Comment: I only got the first one (which is the battery level, everything else was 0). And what I need the most are 2 and 5!